# matplotlib not displaying all axis values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I have a small program that is plotting some data.  The program runs without any errors and displays the plot, but it is removing every other x-axis value.  What should I be doing to get all twelve axis labels to display properly?

The program:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pandas.plotting import register_matplotlib_converters

print('NumPy: {}'.format(np.__version__))
print('Pandas: {}'.format(pd.__version__))
print('-----')

display_settings = {
    'max_columns': 14,
    'expand_frame_repr': False,  # Wrap to multiple pages
    'max_rows': 50,
    'show_dimensions': False
}
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:,.2f}'.format

for op, value in display_settings.items():
    pd.set_option("display.{}".format(op), value)

file = "e:\\python\\dataquest\\unrate.csv"
unrate = pd.read_csv(file)
print(unrate.shape, '\n')

unrate['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(unrate['DATE'])
print(unrate.info(), '\n')
print(unrate.head(12), '\n')

register_matplotlib_converters()
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.plot(unrate['DATE'][0:12], unrate['VALUE'][0:12])
plt.show()
```

I am getting as output:  (I am using PyCharm)

[image]

I believe I should be getting: (From Dataquests built in IDE)

[image]

Comment: Use `matplotlib.dates.DateLocator('M')`?

Answer (score 0):

@Quang Hong,  You were on the right track.  I had to adjust the interval value and the date format as follows:

plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%b %Y'))
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator(interval=30))

Now I get this output:

[image]